# Python MySQLdb get connection details

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Is there a way to access information like the host, username, and password from a MySQLdb connection object after `MySQLdb.connect()` has already been called?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be way of retrieving the connection parameters. Or least one that could be recommended.

I've been looking at all the variables and methods of the object (in ipython you can invoke  **dict** over the object that has the connection, e.g. conn.**dict**) and the list given is something like:

```
{'_server_version': (5, 6),
 '_transactional': 8192L,
 'cursorclass': MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor,
 'encoders': {bool: <function MySQLdb.converters.Bool2Str>,
  instance: <function MySQLdb.converters.Instance2Str>,
  float: <function MySQLdb.converters.Float2Str>,
  int: <function MySQLdb.converters.Thing2Str>,
  list: <function MySQLdb.converters.quote_tuple>,
  long: <function MySQLdb.converters.Thing2Str>,
  dict: <function _mysql.escape_dict>,
  NoneType: <function MySQLdb.converters.None2NULL>,
  set: <function MySQLdb.converters.Set2Str>,
  str: <function MySQLdb.connections.string_literal>,
  tuple: <function MySQLdb.converters.quote_tuple>,
  object: <function MySQLdb.converters.Instance2Str>,
  unicode: <function MySQLdb.connections.unicode_literal>,
  datetime.timedelta: <function MySQLdb.times.DateTimeDelta2literal>,
  datetime.datetime: <function MySQLdb.times.DateTime2literal>,
  array.array: <function MySQLdb.converters.array2Str>},
 'messages': [],
 'string_decoder': <function MySQLdb.connections.string_decoder>,
 'unicode_literal': <function MySQLdb.connections.unicode_literal>}
```

By navigating through the code "connect" returns an instance of the class Connection that extends the existing _mysql.connection class. Here you can find functions like "get_host_info" that you could invoke directly on the connection obj but doesn't seem to provide that I think you are looking for.

A way of retrieving that data is creating a new class which contains the connection and the parameters given to it.

Hope that helps,
Gemma